# How to show number of connections as edge label and weight based on number of connections

Tags: python, networkx

How to show the number of connections as edge label and edge weight based on number of connections.

My code so far:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('a','b');
G.add_edge('c','d');
G.add_edge('c','a');
G.add_edge('a','b');
G.add_edge('b','a');

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

My objective is to create a graph based on a large amount of data (Python script)

newbie to networkx and matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem that you run into, is that `networkx` is not really suited for plotting weighted, directed graphs. It can be done, but it ain't pretty. 
In particular, there is no real support for plotting bi-directional connections, as bi-directional connections are plotted on top of each other.
Below I try to get around that by plotting the edge weight near the head of the connection, but that doesn't work really well.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edge('a','b');
G.add_edge('c','d');
G.add_edge('c','a');
G.add_edge('a','b');
G.add_edge('b','a');

edge_to_count = dict()
for edge in G.edges():
    try:
        edge_to_count[edge] += 1
    except KeyError:
        edge_to_count[edge] = 1

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_to_count, label_pos=0.25)

plt.show()
```

If you want to represent the multi-edges as an edge weight, then the code changes to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# get edge weights based on edge count
edges = [('a','b'),
         ('c','d'),
         ('c','a'),
         ('a','b'),
         ('b','a')]

edge_to_count = dict()
for edge in edges:
    try:
        edge_to_count[edge] += 1.
    except KeyError:
        edge_to_count[edge] = 1.

# convert to networkx edge list format
edges = [(k[0], k[1], dict(weight=v)) for k, v in edge_to_count.items()]

# create graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# precompute layout to be used by both, draw() and draw_networkx_edge_labels
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# draw graph first, then labels on top
nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_to_count, label_pos=0.25)

plt.show()
```

## Addendum

At some point, I battled with this exact problem for a while so I wrote my own little network plotting library called `netgraph` (available via pip and on [github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph)). The API is very similar to networkx, with the exception that I got rid of some naming inconsistencies that I suspect were kept in networkx for backwards compatibility. The default output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it supports plotting of bi-directional / parallel edges. Edges are colored according to their weight by default. As it accepts networkx graph objects as input, it's fairly easy to integrate with networkx (it supports a variety of input formats as well).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx
import netgraph

# get edge weights based on edge count
edges = [('a','b'),
         ('c','d'),
         ('c','a'),
         ('a','b'),
         ('b','a')]

edge_to_count = dict()
for edge in edges:
    try:
        edge_to_count[edge] += 1.
    except KeyError:
        edge_to_count[edge] = 1.

# convert to networkx edge list format
edges = [(k[0], k[1], dict(weight=v)) for k, v in edge_to_count.items()]

# create graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# draw
netgraph.draw(G, edge_labels=edge_to_count, edge_label_font_size=8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Many thanks !. Can you recommend another one for weighted, directed graphs ?

Comment: I wrote my own network plotting library called `netgraph` (installable via pip / on [github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph)). I just realised that my edge label plotting code has an issue with bidirectional edges as well. Give me 10 more minutes and it should be fixed. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: Added netgraph example. Sorry for the delay; fixing bugs always takes longer than I anticipate.